# Python - Using method and functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32, win32com, autodesk-inventor

I want to write a script that is able to read a structure from a AutoDesk Inventor Model. Inventor is installed and running and a connection to it through win32.com is established.
After loading the model an setting a few variables I'm stuck.

I have this list
oStructuredBOMView.BOMRows

```
>> print(len(oStructuredBOMView.BOMRows))
2
```

I can reference one item

```
>> print(oStructuredBOMView.BOMRows.Item(1))
<win32com.gen_py.Autodesk Inventor Object Library.BOMRow instance at 0x88831536>
```

And with a dir I can display all functions/methods

```
>> print(dir(oStructuredBOMView.BOMRows.Item(1)))
['CLSID', 'GetReferenceKey', '_ApplyTypes_', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_get_good_object_', '_get_good_single_object_', '_oleobj_', '_prop_map_get_', '_prop_map_put_', 'coclass_clsid']
```

This ist the point I can't exceed. How can I use this functions/methods to extract more information? 
Example:

```
>> oStructuredBOMView.BOMRows.Item(1).sizeof
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    oStructuredBOMView.BOMRows.Item(1).sizeof
  File "C:\python\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 473, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Autodesk Inventor Object Library.BOMRow        instance at 0x88417896>' object has no attribute 'sizeof'

>> sizeof(oStructuredBOMView.BOMRows.Item(1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
sizeof(oStructuredBOMView.BOMRows.Item(1))
NameError: name 'sizeof' is not defined
```

Comment: Using COM objects does not follow the usual best practice examples of how to use functions and method in Python. Please show us what `oStructuredBOMView.BOMRows` actually is!

Comment: You have `__sizeof__` in the output of `dir()`, not `sizeof`.

Comment: `>>> oStructuredBOMView.BOMRows` `<win32com.gen_py.Autodesk Inventor Object Library.BOMRowsEnumerator instance at 0x88853752>`

Comment: `type(oStructuredBOMView.BOMRows)` `<class 'win32com.gen_py.D98A091D-3A0F-4C3E-B36E-61F62068D488x0x1x0.BOMRowsEnumerator'>`

Answer (score 1):

First, sizeof is no valid python function so your second try won't work.

Second, your attribute of the BOMRows Item object is named `__sizeof__`, so you have to use that and not just 'sizeof':

```
oStructuredBOMView.BOMRows.Item(1).__sizeof__
```

Third, those are just attributes of the object, they may or may not be functions/methods, you can find out which are callable with:

```
isMethod = callable(oStructuredBOMView.BOMRows.Item(1).__sizeof__)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable

Update: You can try to `print()` all the attributes (this is kind of obvious, so you maybe already tried that). As I don't know anything about AutoDesk Inventor models, I can't help you with a direct response, but you could try to dig deeper into the object. If the attribute is a 'primitive type' (read: printable object or object that has some string representation) you can use it directly. If your attribute returns another object, then you have to analyze it again with `dir()` or `vars()` again. You can ignore most of the double underscore attributes, as they are most likely from python.

Example of trying to print all attributes of an unknown object:

```
for key in dir(my_obj):
    print('{}: {}'.format(key, getattr(my_obj, key))
```

But I am sure there should be some documentation available how to use the Autodesk Inventor objects.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Now I have to figure out how to read the attributes or get the fuctions to work.

Comment: Perfekt @Frieder That helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The inventor object browser is your best friend to see the properties and methods of each class in inventor. To open it go to the VBA editor and press F2.

```
>> print(oStructuredBOMView.BOMRows.Item(1))
<win32com.gen_py.Autodesk Inventor Object Library.BOMRow instance at 0x88831536>
```

This tells you that the class is BOMRow. Type the class name into the search field and go from there.